# Java Data Objects Specification using only Runtime Exceptions?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, runtimeexception, jsr

We are evaluating JDO for using as the Data Management Layer in our application . The requirement is to have a well abstracted Data management with zero dependencies with any of the Data stores.

We found JDO very promising and is understanding the Data nucleus implementation.

One prominent thing came into our consideration is that JDO is predominantly following a runtime exception strategy.

See
http://docs.tpu.ru/docs/oracle/en/fmw/11.1.1.6.0/apirefs.1111/e13946/jdo_overview_arch.html

The parent exception to all JDO exceptions are javax.jdo.JDOException and is extending the Runtime Exception.

We understand that exceptions that are raised while calling the API are obviously runtime. But if we had a checked exception had it been easy to manage ?

Please comment on this . Can some one help in understanding the philosophy of using Runtime exceptions through out the API .

Comment: There are ample debates/discussions on checked .v. unchecked exceptions on the web (do a search). The fact is that JDO and JPA both adopted unchecked exceptions to not impose on the user of those interfaces, and all possible thrown exceptions are adequately documented in javadocs and the respective specs.

Comment: When it comes to exceptions, there are two distinct sects in Java. One believes what you (and i) do, that checked exceptions are a powerful kind of documentation of an interface, and force errors to be addressed explicitly. The other believes what the JDO authors (and perhaps @subramanya) do, that checked exceptions are mostly an annoyance, and a risk of abstraction leakage. Neither sect can understand how the other could possibly believe what they believe. It's been this way for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the use of making the api throw Runtime exception.
Please follow this link. It is nice
http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html

One quote from above link says

Never let implementation-specific checked exceptions escalate to the higher layers. For example, do not propagate SQLException from data access code to the business objects layer. Business objects layer do not need to know about SQLException. You have two options:

Convert SQLException into another checked exception, if the client code is expected to recuperate from the exception.

Convert SQLException into an unchecked exception, if the client code cannot do anything about it.

Most of the time, client code cannot do anything about SQLExceptions. Do not hesitate to convert them into unchecked exceptions.

I think this  clearly explains the benefit of runtime exceptions

Comment: Thank you subramanya for a prompt answer. I can see the advantage of using an unchecked exception but if you look it from another angle. Say when i am calling a method or in oops I am using a behavior of an object. Should the method signature explicitly say what would happen if it couldn't satisfy the intended behavior.

Comment: This is particularly useful when  I am calling an API. API signature explicitly tells the behavior rather than depend on an unchecked exception which can be thrown differently by any implementation. Is this a violation of program to interface design principle.

Comment: What is the best way to handle these runtime exceptions from JDO API. What I have seen in the Spring adapters for JDO is that they wrap these APIs and create checked exceptions and throw it from the wrappers. But it dilutes the purpose of having an API.